# Connection string for .xlsx

Tags: excel, connection-string

I am trying to connect to Excel. There are no problems to open .xls but .xlsx (Excel 2013) failed using connection string:

1. work with old version:

   ```
   Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + %1 + ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1'
   ```

With .xlsx it returns error about wrong file format.

2. try new one:

   ```
   Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='"+ %1 +"';Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1';
   ```

receives error *Could not find installable ISAM*.

I found proposition to find out msexcl40.dll and run "regsvr32 msexcl40.dll". I do it, now both versions return errors.

Could you help me to resolve?

Office version - Office 365 2013